# If you were traveling at the same speed as an accelerating electron, would the electron still produce EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reference-frames, velocity, inertial-frames

For simplicity, let's say that an electron is moving through an antenna and producing electromagnetic waves as it travels. To the extent of my knowledge, these waves are produced by the movement of the electron in the antenna's electromagnetic field (please correct me if I am wrong!). Now, let's say that you are the size of an electron and you are moving with the same velocity as the electron in the antenna. According to your reference frame, the electron is stationary, but would it still produce waves? If so, why?

Thank you in advance, and I apologize if I've overlooked an obvious answer! :)

Comment: There is no requirement that the physics would be the same unless the observer's frame is an inertial one.  Since you are accelerating, you are not at rest in an inertial frame.

Comment: I am not sure this problem is settled: https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0506049%E2%80%8E and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_a_charge_in_a_gravitational_field I believe the arguments there also apply to an accelerated observed in special relativity.

Comment: [Do the desired coordinate transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity)

Comment: I mean, though inertial observers can detect electromagnetic
radiation emitted from a uniformly accelerated charge, comoving observers will see only a static
electric field. If that is correct, there is radiation but it cannot be seen because it is beyond the rindler horizon

Comment: I believe you would see radiation, but you would interpret it as scattering by the electron of the Unruh radiation coming from the Rindler horizon.

Comment: A few related questions on accelerated charged particles: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286457/charged-particle-as-observed-from-an-inertial-and-a-non-inertial-frame-of-refere , http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70915/does-a-constantly-accelerating-charged-particle-emit-em-radiation-or-not , http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278270/will-a-charged-particle-stationary-in-its-reference-frame-appear-to-radiate-to-a

Answer (score 2):

1. yes they would
2. the reason is, that the accelerating electron emits photons at the speed of light, to any external observer
3. so any external observer, you too would see those photons traveling at speed c, regardless if you are accelerating or are stationary compared to the electron
4. it is not your (the observer's) relationship to the electron that matters, it is that the electron has to accelerate compared to the antenna to start emitting photons